# Protecting against malformed content

Tags: html, dom

So I have a use case where I am putting 3rd party content into part of a page. I do not have any control over the content and cannot modify it.

The content often has closing tags that do not have a corresponding opening tag. This causes issues with the rest of the page.

Right now the only way that I can think of to protect myself from the closing tags is to put the entire content in an iframe.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you have the ability to do any preprocessing on the content before it is appended?

Comment: cannot you parse the content even with javascript as text ?

Comment: Are you appending dynamically?  You can see if jquery can build a DOM structure out of it via `$(content)`.

Comment: The content is coming down through a spring controller and the model is dumped to the dom with jsp tag ${someModel}

Comment: @zmanc well then you can skip the html tags with java, did you try this ?

Comment: @ProgMania, I do not want to skip all the tags, just random tags that are not closing anything.

Comment: There is only those 2 that I know that work. The Iframe when you can't replace table tags and the table hack if you can replace table,tr and td. I've seen regex solution and manually combing through the html, though I've never used them thinking they are too slow and too vunerable.

Answer (score 0):

Better or better. I've had so many interesting variants of this because I work mostly with intigration projects.

I've come to down to this solution. Which is not as robust as Iframe which is my last resort in these matters.

But I replace all the table tags before throwing the content into the td.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Massivly bad content</div> and silly stuff</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what happens if they have a closing table or a closing td?

Comment: what about the browsers comp. with this, i think internet explorer will reject it ?